# Синхронизация между слайдами Slick и элементами списка HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, slick.js

## Приветствую!

`!!!`[Вот здесь](https://codepen.io/Kreami/pen/jZjQEw) я мудрил со слайдером. Нужна помощь вот с чем: при перелистывании слайдов, должен подчеркиваться привязанный к нему элемент списка, то есть:

1 слайд - подчеркнут 1й элемент списка
2 слайд - подчеркнут 2й элемент списка
3 слайд - подчеркнут 3й элемент списка

Не имею даже представления как это реализуется. Буду благодарен если кто поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день, как то так. Вся нужная информация для того что бы сделать есть на сайте слайдера

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.howto-slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false
  });
  $('.howto-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $('ul li:nth(' + nextSlide + ')').addClass('underline').siblings().removeClass('underline');
  });
});
```

```css
.howto-slider {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.howto-item {
  bg: white;
  padding: 6rem 0;
}

.howto-item ul {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.howto-item ul li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.slick-slider {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slick-dots {
  bottom: 25px;
}

.slick-dots li button::before {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
.underline {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="howto-item">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 col-10 offset-1">
          <h2>Как сдать Судебный/Досудебный тест</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione magnam harum voluptate delectus ex quod quia voluptatibus iste saepe quaerat!</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore delectus porro, temporibus asperiores exercitationem eos quia tempora laborum ad illum!</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem quas repudiandae voluptates cumque ipsum culpa voluptatibus sed, laboriosam, iusto molestias?</li>
          </ul>
          <button class="button more-link">Подробнее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="howto-slider">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```